# Prove that A is dense in ℝ if for every open set U of ℝ there exists a point of A in U.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

Let A be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose A has the property that for every open set U of $\mathbb{R}$ there exists a point of A in U. Prove that A is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Basically we know that A covers the real numbers so any real number must be in the union of the indexed family of sets.

My solution: Suppose A is not dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Then there exists $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that for all sequences $x_n$ in A, $x_n$ does not converge to x. Thus, there exists an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ $I_r(k)$ such that (k-r,k+r) does not contain x. This is a contradiction since A is an open cover of $\mathbb{R}$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What do you mean by "$A$ covers the real numbers"? And for "A is an open cover of $\mathbb{R}?$

Comment: I think that an open cover means that we basically have a family of open intervals such that any real number is in one of these intervals.

Comment: You're trying to prove "A is dense" $\implies$ "for every open...".  Whether you're proving directly,  by contradiction, or by contrapositive, your proof should **not** begin with "suppose $A$ is not dense".

Comment: In order for $A$ to be an open cover, $A$ would have to be a set whose elements are intervals.  However, the elements of $A$ are just real numbers, since $A \subset \Bbb R$.

Comment: My previous comment was mistaken; I was wrong about what you're supposed to prove.  It's actually, "for every open..." $\implies$ "A is dense", so you're fine

Comment: Ok, I was unclear since in my title. I switched the order.

Comment: So I am proving the correct thing, although my proof is incorrect at the moment?

Comment: That's right. ${}$

Comment: So basically we have a bunch of open sets say (-1,1),(-2,2),(-3,3)... and each of these intervals contains a point in the set A.

Comment: And any open interval in the set of real numbers contains a point in A.

Comment: But they're not intervals you said, they are just a sequence of real numbers and each sequence contains an element of A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest thing to the proof you started is a proof by contrapositive.  That is, we will show that "$A$ is not dense" implies that "for every open $U$..." is false.

Now, we have to understand what it is that we're trying to prove.  In particular, we should note that

> not (for every open set $U$ of $ℝ$: there exists a point of $A$ in $U$) =
>   There exists an open set $U$ of $\Bbb R$ such that: not (there exists a point of $A$ in $U$)  =
>   There exists an open set $U$ of $\Bbb R$ such that: $U$ contains no points of $A$ =
>   **There exists an open set $U$ of $\Bbb R$ such that: $U \cap A = \emptyset$**

Now, suppose that $A$ is not dense.  Then, there is some $x \in \Bbb R$ such that *no sequence made from the elements of $A$* converges to $x$.  Now, the tricky consequence of this statement is:

> there is some $r > 0$ such that $(x-r,x+r)$ contains no elements of $A$

I would not consider this an "easy" proof.  From there, if we define $U = (x-r,x+r)$, then $U$ is exactly the kind of open set we wanted.  That ends the proof.

Personally, I would have preferred to go through the direct proof here.

---

**Direct Proof:** Suppose that $A$ is such that every open set $U$ contains some element of $A$.  Now, pick any $x \in \Bbb R$
Our goal is to prove that there is a sequence $x_n \to x$ for which each $x_n$ is an element of $A$.  In other words, our goal is to *build* such a sequence.

Here's how we would build the sequence: for each integer $n\geq 1$, $I_{1/n}(x)$ is an open set, and must therefore contain an element of $A$.  For every such integer $n$, pick any element from $I_{1/n}(x) \cap A$, and call that element $x_n$.  The sequence built in this fashion converges to $x$, as you should verify using the definition of convergence.

Since $x$ was an arbitrary element of $\Bbb R$, the same thing works for *every* $x$, which tells us that $A$ is dense.

Comment: So basically we have intervals (x - 1/n, x + 1/n) and the intervals shrink as n increases, and this converges to the midpoint x.

Comment: And we know the intervals for each n contains an element of A by the assumption

Comment: Are you saying that the *intervals* converge to the midpoint?  What do you mean by that?

Comment: I guess that doesn't make sense. So $x_1$ shall be a point in the interval (x - 1/1, x + 1/1), and so on for each n.

Comment: @JohnH right, a point in the interval, and a point in $A$.  Again, being comfortable with the definition of convergence is very useful here.

Comment: And if that point $x_1$ was say x + .0000001, it would not matter since eventually the intervals would be even smaller than that and so the point you choose would have to be even closer to x than that

Comment: @JohnH exactly.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I think convergence is becoming more clear now.